# fetchIfNeeded causes freezing/hanging

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, android-anr-dialog

I am developing an android app using the parse API. I have noticed that after migration, every time I call fetchIfNeeded() or fetchIfNeededInBackground() it only works well if the user has very fast internet. Otherwise, if the internet is slow or if the user is not connected, the app freezes, which is definitely not good. It is especially bad when used in an adapter as the listview scrolling is very jittery. Please help me handle this problem